# How does Chainmail Agility work?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

Can a chainmail speed penalty be more than -1? If not, isn't Chainmail Agility inferior to the Fleet-Footed feat (+1 feat bonus to your speed)? Do these feats stack?

Comment: I removed your second question. If you want to ask two questions, post them as two separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using chainmail, Chainmail Agility & Fleet-Footed essentially do the same thing. Fleet-Footed is *slightly* better in that you still get its benefit if you for some reason take off your armor, and unlike Chainmail Agility it helps dwarves (who always ignore armor penalties to speed).

Their effects *do* stack; Fleet-Footed gives a feat bonus to speed (and therefore does *not* stack with anything else that gives a feat bonus to speed), while Chainmail Agility reduces a penalty rather than giving a bonus.

Comment: Also, you can always take any feat you meet the prerequisites for. If you have an epic tier character, you can still take heroic & paragon tier feats. Whether it's a good idea to do that depends entirely on your character, but it generally the more complex your build is, the more likely it is that there will be some good heroic tier feats that you either don't have room for until epic tier or don't have all the other pieces to combo with the feat until epic tier.

Comment: I tried to plan my character to lvl 30 (i hope he will survive) can i show you the list of feats? Im not sure all i want will stack.